# How can I get fully-classified class name in PHPStorm's Code Completion?

Tags: namespaces, phpstorm

I'm new to PHPStorm and want to ask how can I get fully-classified class name (absolute path to the class) using Code Completion (Command+Space)?

For example, I have a function in my code:

```
<?php

namespace A;
use C\D\Class;

/**
 * @return Class (what PHPStorm suggests)
 * @return \C\D\Class (what I need)
 */
function foo() {
  return new Class();
}
?>
```

This function returns an instance of \C\D\Class
When generating docblock for this function, I use Command+Space to place class name after @return keyword. PHPStorm suggests Class in the expanded list but when I select necessary class it places only "Class" instead of "\C\D\Class".

How can I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 27):

I had the same issue too.
Actually it is very simple, but I also did not find the option. It is well hidden.

Open the settings and go to:

IDE Settings -> Editor -> Auto Import

[image: Settings dialog in PhpStorm]

There you'll find the checkbox "Enable auto-import in namespace scope". Uncheck it, and namespaces will not be shorten anymore using the"use" keyword.

But now PhpStorm will tell you that it is unnecessary to use the complete namespace. To avoid that just disable the inspection "Unnecessary fully qualified name".

[image: Inspections in settings dialog in PhpStorm]

You are still able to tell PhpStorm to import the current class' namespace. For me it is just marking the class with the cursor and pressing ALT+ENTER. Then this dialog appears:

[image: Import class dialog]

When I confirm with ENTER the namespace of this class becomes imported and shorten:
[image: Shorten class name]

Comment: Depends on your key-settings, I guess. It is possible that I am not using the phpstorm defaults (moved from netbeans to phpstorm)

Comment: As of 2017 (on Mac at least) the option can be found in Editor -> General -> Auto Import

Comment: Btw. Now, I'm always importing the Namespaces. It does not only make the code easier to read, it also shows - in top of the plain php file - all dependencies to other classes and third party vendors.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the only way to do so is start typing `\C\D\Cla` and then complete. If this is not what you want feel free to create a Usability issue on [Issue Tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/).